# Is there any cordova plugin that allows multiple banners/Ads in a single screen?

Tags: cordova, plugins, ionic-framework, ads, banner-ads

I have a requirement to show multiple banners(say more than 3) in a single screen of an ionic app. Since Admob cordova plugin is allowing only 2, is there any other plugin that allows more than 3 ads in a single screen.

Answer (score 1):

More than 1 ad per screen and placing ads replacing app content is against policy. Your app will be rejected (watch the video here or see documentation here).

As Nitin explained, you can place one banner at top and another at bottom if they are not visible at the same time.

Placing ads between the content and the menu is not recommended (and your app will probably be rejected too as it can be considered to "encourage accidental clicks"). The ad should not be confused with app content (I'm not sure if it is against policy but they clearly mention it in the video as a key point).

If you are using this cordova plugin

cordova plugin add com.admob.google
you will be able to decide between placing the ads at the bottom or at top (see cordova admob documentation):

```
function onDeviceReady() {
  document.removeEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);
  admob.setOptions({
    publisherId: "YOUR_PUBLISHER_ID",
    bannerAtTop: true
  });
  admob.createBannerView();
}
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
```